# Writting adapted functions in R - error in output calculation

Tags: r, matlab

I have two functions written in MATLAB (`distitpf` and `distchpf` from the voicebox toolbox) and I'm trying to convert them to R. These functions calculate the Itakura distance and the COSH distance. Below is the code of those functions and the code I've written so far in R. My problem is when i test my R functions I  get an error. Any ideas what the error is and how to solve them?

Functions in MATLAB:

```
function d=distitpf(pf1,pf2)
[nf1,p2]=size(pf1);
p1=p2-1;
nf2=size(pf2,1);
  nx=min(nf1,nf2);
  r=pf1(1:nx,:)./pf2(1:nx,:);
  q=log(r);
  d=log((sum(r(:,2:p1),2)+0.5*(r(:,1)+r(:,p2)))/p1)-(sum(q(:,2:p1),2)+0.5*(q(:,1)+q(:,p2)))/p1;
end

function d=distchpf(pf1,pf2)
[nf1,p2]=size(pf1);
p1=p2-1;
nf2=size(pf2,1);
nx=min(nf1,nf2);
r=pf1(1:nx,:)./pf2(1:nx,:);
q=r+r.^(-1);
d=(2*sum(q(:,2:p1),2)+q(:,1)+q(:,p2))/(4*p1)-1;
end
```

Functions in R:

```
distitpf <- function(pf1,pf2){  
 nf1=nrow(pf1)
 p2=length(pf1);
 p1=p2-1;
 nf2=nrow(pf2);   
 nx=min(nf1,nf2);
 r=pf1[1:nx,]/pf2[1:nx,];
 qx=log(r);
 d=log((sum(r[,2:p1],2)+0.5*(r[,1]+r[,p2]))/p1)-(sum(qx[,2:p1],2)+0.5*(qx[,1]+qx[,p2]))/p1;
 return(d)}

 distchpf <- function(pf1,pf2) {
 nf1=nrow(pf1)
 p2=length(pf1);
 p1=p2-1;
 nf2=nrow(pf2);
 nx=min(nf1,nf2);
 r=pf1[1:nx,]/pf2[1:nx,];
 qx=r+r^(-1);
 d=(2*sum(qx[,2:p1],2)+qx[,1]+qx[,p2])/(4*p1)-1;
 return(d)}
```

Testing for MATLAB:

```
pf1=[2,4,5,6];
pf2=[7,8,9,1];
>> distitpf(pf1,pf2)
ans =
    0.6732
>> distchpf(pf1,pf2)
ans =
    0.6386
```

Testing for R:

```
pf1=c(2,4,5,6);
pf2=c(7,8,9,1);
> distchpf(pf1,pf2)
Error in 1:nx : result would be too long a vector
In addition: Warning message:
In min(nf1, nf2) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> distitpf(pf1,pf2)
Error in 1:nx : result would be too long a vector
In addition: Warning message:
In min(nf1, nf2) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

(EDIT)
I've solved the problem. I post the corrected R code below.

```
distitpf <- function(pf1,pf2){ 
  pf1<-as.matrix(pf1)
  pf2<-as.matrix(pf2)
  nf1=nrow(pf1)
  p2=length(pf1);
  p1=p2-1;
  nf2=nrow(pf2); 

  nx=min(nf1,nf2);
  r=pf1/pf2
  qx=log(r);
  d=log((sum(r[2:p1])+0.5*(r[1]+r[p2]))/p1)-(sum(qx[2:p1])+0.5*(qx[1]+qx[p2]))/p1;
  return(d)}

distchpf <- function(pf1,pf2) {
  pf1<-as.matrix(pf1)
  pf2<-as.matrix(pf2)
  nf1=nrow(pf1)
  p2=length(pf1);
  p1=p2-1;
  nf2=nrow(pf2);

  r=pf1/pf2;
  qx=r+r^(-1);
  d=(2*sum(qx[2:p1])+qx[1]+qx[p2])/(4*p1)-1;

  return(d)}
```

Comment: What the error is, is listed quite clearly by R.

Comment: yes but how do i solve it?

Comment: Your input (two vectors) does not have any rows. Check out what `nrow(pf1)` returns. Only matrix-like objects have rows.

Comment: you're right. thanks for the help

Comment: @Filipa, could you advise the reasons to write this functions by yourself. It looks like they are available in `seewave` or `proxy` libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The answer goes out to Filipa. However I would use already implemented functions in `seeway` and `proxy` libraries:

```
distitpf <- function(pf1, pf2) { 
  pf1 <- as.matrix(pf1)
  pf2 <- as.matrix(pf2)
  nf1 <- nrow(pf1)
  p2 <- length(pf1)
  p1 <- p2 - 1
  nf2 <- nrow(pf2) 

  nx <- min(nf1, nf2)
  r <- pf1 / pf2
  qx <- log(r)

  log((sum(r[2:p1]) + 0.5 * (r[1] + r[p2])) / p1) - (sum(qx[2:p1]) + 0.5 * (qx[1] + qx[p2])) / p1
}

distchpf <- function(pf1, pf2) {
  pf1 <- as.matrix(pf1)
  pf2 <- as.matrix(pf2)
  nf1 <- nrow(pf1)
  p2 <- length(pf1)
  p1 <- p2 - 1
  nf2 <- nrow(pf2)

  r <- pf1 / pf2
  qx <- r + 1 / r

  (2 * sum(qx[2:p1]) + qx[1] + qx[p2]) / (4 * p1) - 1
}
```